# Do we still need "script.type='text/javascript" when creating a script dynamically?

Tags: javascript

The code is like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
//script.type = 'text/javascript'; // do I need this ?
script.src = src;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The second line has been commented out because it makes no difference to have it.
Or am I missing something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No: The default value of `type` is already set to JavaScript ("text/javascript"). The type attribute is a property of the SCRIPT tag to allow Vbscript, for example, which is only supported by IE.

The `type` attribute has also become optional in HTML5. This could be an encouragement to omit the `type` attribute of the `script` element.

Comment: @jcolebrand
"...to allow Vbscript, *for example*, ...". The OP asked whether it's necessary to add `type="text/javascript"` or not.

Comment: True, but you're saying that it's almost not even used anymore. I was pointing out one very valid use that people are _more likely_ to encounter nowadays. But that link _also_ backs up your statement (as the jQuery team aren't using text on generic script tags)

Answer (score 8):

No. It's probably not strictly correct in html4 but it shouldn't cause you any problems.

[HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)

```
"The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data..." 
"...The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is 'text/javascript'."
```

The only thing I have noticed is that IDE's sometimes don't use the correct syntax highlighting when you don't specify a type. I have found this in Coda for the Mac, it's the only reason I ever put it in now.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will work without it.

If you are generating HTML 4 or XHTML 1 then leaving it out would be non-conformant.

If you are generating HTML, then it is explicitly optional.

Answer (score 1):

The **type** `attribute` is required in HTML 4 and XHTML, but optional in HTML5.